# Limit width of formatted user input - Javascript, CSS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, textarea, user-input

How do you prevent formatted user input past a max width? (e.g., 800 pixels)  The user input is formatted because it is entered into a WYSIWYG text editor (CK Editor).

This solution doesn't work:

```
// Replicate user input in hidden div  
// Check width  
// If width > 800px, remove characters
```

...because you'd be removing characters from a formatted entry - e.g., from `<p>Hello World</p>` you'd end up with `<p>Hello World</p`

Comment: Keep in mind, that the browser of the editor may have different settings/fonts/etc. than the browser of the viewer later, so that the text will be wider than 800px in the viewers browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can already find the width of the
>   formatted string. The problem is in
>   the actually shortening of it.

I think given your problem it *is* possible to remove the last char from a formatted entry. You'd just have to recursively dig through your HTML structure till you find it. Have a look at this neat little function I've written:

```
function findLastElement(element){
    var content = $.trim(element.html());

    if(content.charAt(content.length - 1) === '>'){
        var lastChild = element.children(':last');
        if(lastChild.length > 0){
          return findLastElement(lastChild);
        }
    }

    return element;
}
```

The name is slightly misleading, but this function will dig through the jQuery element you pass to it to find the element containing the last character, so I think this will solve your problem.

PS. I'd readily accept any suggestion on how to optimize/adopt best practice with this piece of code, if any of the gurus here would kindly drop one in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Can we assume only a certain font will be used? This one might help:

[Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)

Comment: Unfortunately not.  But I can already find the width of the formatted string.  The problem is in the actually shortening of it.